# how to get current cell.contentview in uicollectionview. how to add subview in uicollectionview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

Hi in my application i want to add particular view in cell.contentview now situation is that where i can add this code. reason is if i am puting this code on cellforitematindexpath it will be added in last cell(indxpath.row) reason is in cellforrowatindexpath last cell will be loaded last so view will be added in last cell. while i want it on that cell which was displaying at current time

Here is my code. simply have to add subview

```
 let cell : pdfImageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "pdfImageCell", for: indexPath) as! pdfImageCell


 cell.contentView.addSubview(userResizableView1)
```

Comment: "while i want it on that cell which was displaying at current time" - 

It's possible multiple cells are displaying at the same time. So which exactly are you looking to add this subview to?

Comment: share  code full cellForItemAtIndexPath method

Comment: i am displaying only one cell at a time@raidfive

Answer (score 0):

You can add `UIView` in `awakeFromNib()` method. It will get the call only once.

```
class pdfImageCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    //you can add here
    override func awakeFromNib() {

        var userResizableView1 = UIView()
        self.contentView.addSubview(userResizableView1)
    }

}
```

Comment: but i am getting userResizableView1 in my viewcontroller class so how can i use that in uitableviewcell class?

Comment: you can add userResizableView1 in awakeFromNib() method then set userResizableView1.hidden = true. in you cellforitematindexpath  if you want to display then you can set userResizableView1.hidden = false

Answer (score 0):

Get the visible cell index like below in `UICollectionView`. You can also get multiple cells visible if they are visible on screen so selected the cell you want.

```
var visibleCurrentCell: IndexPath? {
    for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells {
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        return indexPath
     }    
     return nil
}
```

Then get the cell from your index and add the subview in that cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths
```

Here it is a method to reload the specific indexPaths in your collectionView

you can update your datasource on click and your cellForItemAtIndex will know from your data source that it has to have the subview this time

```
if (datasourcearray[indexpPath.row].isSubViewToBeAdded)
{
    self.contentview.addsubview(subViewToBeAdded)
}
```